# If $A$ and $B$ are vectors in $\mathbb C^n$, prove that $-2 \le \frac{A\cdot B + \overline{A\cdot B}}{|A||B|} \le 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, upper-lower-bounds

If $A$ and $B$ are vectors in $\mathbb C^n$, the exercise is to prove that:

$$-2 \le \frac{A\cdot B + \overline{A\cdot B}}{|A||B|} \le 2.$$

I tried using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $|A\cdot B| \le |A||B|$, but it only work with the modulus.

I guess it is possible to convert this identity to real vectors, stating that $\mathbb C^n$ is isometric to $\mathbb R^{2n}$, but I am unable to formalise and prove this.

Comment: If you multiply through by $\frac12\lvert A\rvert\lvert B\rvert$, you get $-\lvert A\rvert\lvert B\rvert\leq \operatorname{Re}(A\cdot B)\leq \lvert A\rvert\lvert B\rvert$. Is it easier to prove this? (I'm assuming $A\cdot B$ is the dot product, so in $\mathbb C$.)

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is real part of ab for ab complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:
$$(A\cdot B+\overline{A\cdot B})^2 = (A\cdot B)^2+2(A\cdot B)(\overline{A\cdot B})+(\overline{A\cdot B})^2\leq $$
$$\leq 2|A|^2|B|^2+2\Re((A\cdot B)^2)\leq 2|A|^2|B|^2+2|A\cdot B|^2\leq 4|A|^2|B|^2.$$
Here, if $z = A\cdot B = a+bi,$ then:
$$z^2+\overline{z}^2 = (a+bi)^2+(a-bi)^2 = 2a^2-2b^2\leq 2a^2+2b^2=2|z|^2.$$